# Import external class in nodejs

Tags: node.js

i´v got a class which i want to export and import it in another file.

```
//db.js    
class sqlConn {
      constru....
}

modules.exports = sqlConn;
```

I tried to import it, but that doenst worked for me...

```
//main.html
var sqlConn = require('path_to_file');
var obj = new sqlConn(...);
```

That gives me following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'path_to_file'
```

can someone help me?

> **Edit** on some answers

I´m using electron with node.js

and my class is laying on an html server.

Also i´m trying to import all in an `index.html` to sahre an `electron.exe` which imports all with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the good path on the required function :

```
var sqlConn = require('./db'); // or other path if the file db.js isn't on the same folder
```

but I see `main.html`, you try to use a node.js code into html?

Comment: `db.js` is on an IIS Server .. so my path seems to be `http://...`. Is that my problem? Yeah, node.js code in html ... i should learn more about node.js

Comment: @KevinLiss You can't run node.js code in browser, it's for server side only (or for desktop apps using Electron).

Comment: @alexmac I´m using electron. Sorry for missing information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ES6/ES2015 you can import the class:

**db.js:**

```
class sqlConn {
   ...
}

export { sqlConn as default }
```

**main.html**:

```
import sqlConn from './path_to_file');
var obj = new sqlConn(...);
```

Comment: Already tried. Gives me error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Answer (score 0):

> Already tried. Gives me error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Did you try the `require` syntaxt?

`const db = require('./db');`

Comment: Like in my question, i already tried the require syntax. Also with "const", if that was your hint.

Comment: You are missing the './' without it will be founded in the node_modules folder

Comment: my script is on an IIS-Webserver ... cant use `./`